# How to convert Java Object to Json and ignore ArrayList on Object?

Tags: java, arraylist, json

I need to convert java Object to json.  I do that with ObjectMapper , like this:

```
static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); .....
String newJsonStringEntity = mapper.writeValueAsString(bean);
```

Everything work  fine, but I want to ignore ArrayList to convert to json, without  `@JsonIgnore` . I want to config mapper if possible?

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, that's one option. But I thought, if there is a solution that does not put the annotation. Perhaps we in some other cases that list should be as Json object. I want to say mapper's  "Ignore ArrayList" , if there is a possible?

Comment: @zexco2: if the normal, obvious way of solving the problem isn't appropriate for your case, you need to say that in your question. It would help if you could explain *why* you have this unusual requirement as well. Do you want to exclude all ArrayList fields? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Read [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization) maybe this helps

Comment: In one java method, I convert Java object to json and then I save that String(for same reports later). But, I want to build json  with only primary fields from Java Object, to ignore ArrayList on Java Object. Something like this , but for ArrayList: mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

Answer (score 2):

You can use two annotation for that:

1. `@JsonIgnore`: This is user for member-level or method-level annotation, which expects that the properties to be excluded one by one.
   You can put this annotation in your bean class.
   Example:

   ```
   @JsonIgnore 
   private ArrayList list;
   ```
2. `@JsonIgnoreProperties` is an annotation at the class level and it expects that the properties to be excluded would be explicitly indicated in the form of a list of strings.
   Example:

   ```
   @JsonIgnoreProperties({"name list variable"})
   class BeanClass {}
   ```

Comment: This is Ok solution for few fields, but if I have thousands of possible objects which I need to convert from JavaObject to JsonObject, then I need to go in every class and put annotation on every ArrayList field. Because, I wont to say on one place, when convert any object , ignore ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

The fields you dont want to convert, dont populate them with values and then use gson. Gson ignores null values. That will solve your problem